# Div Max Width Issue

Tags: web, css

I was able to change my homepage so that the images now stretch full width on the screen. Now I just need to fix the text and content so that it has a max-width of 960px. Below is an image of what I am trying to fix.
If I can get the "Mobile Job Search" section/text back to how the rest of the pages are on the website that would be perfect.

The two divs are .myLeftColumn2 and .myrightColumn2
Any help would be great. Thanks so much!

[image]
www.jobspark.ca

Answer (score 0):

Just add that CSS to your code, I hope that work for other pages too...

CSS

```
#content{
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: When I do that it changes the whole page. I am only looking to target the text so that it doesnt effect the images

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to have to enclose the content below the image in its own div, and restrict it's width.

***Edit*** I looked at the source html, but it is quite messy.

Just to see if this changes anything, located all the divs like this:

```
<div class="row sqs-row" id="yui_3_7_3_1_1369586030814_180">
```

Here's the css :

`.sqs-row {   width: auto !important;   *zoom: 1; }`

edit that width to the width you want (960px)

`.sqs-row {   width: 960px;   *zoom: 1; }`

Comment: i tried that. Can you look at the page and inspect it just so i can see if u came up with something different them me

Comment: I'll look at the page. It's the link you posted?

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole text inside a new div, then write:

```
    #newdiv{
        max-width: 960px;
     }
```

Into your style sheet. This should work perfectly!